# Mapping inside an enum

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum declared like this

```
 public enum KDErrors {

  KDR_280(280, "Blue"),
  KDR_281(281, "Red"),
  KDR_282(282, "Green"),
  KDR_284(284, "Yellow");

  private final int code;
  private final String color;

  private KDErrors(int code, String color) {
    this.code = code;
    this.color = color;
  }

  public static String getColorByCode(int colorCode) {

return ???
  }
}
```

I want to get the value by passing the code, how can I make it work?

Comment: If you are not using Enum instance directly anywhere, just declare a static map and add key-values as code-color and skip the entire enum creation.

Comment: I think it is not a soublicate. OP do not want the Enum, OP wants an other Attribute from the enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code to:

```
public enum KDErrors {

    KDR_280(280, "Blue"), KDR_281(281, "Red"), KDR_282(282, "Green"), KDR_284(284, "Yellow");

    private final int code;

    private final String color;

    private KDErrors(int code, String color) {
        this.code = code;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public static String getColorByCode(int colorCode) {
        for (KDErrors error : KDErrors.values()) {
            if (error.getCode() == colorCode)
                return error.getColor();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reverse lookup map of either you enum or code

Below is an example using reverse look up for enum based on code :

```
public enum KDErrors {

  private static Map<Integer, KDErrors> reverseLookUp = new HashMap<>();

  static{
    for (KDErrors error : KDErrors.values()) {
      reverseLookUp.put(error.code, error);
    }
  }
  //you method would look like
  public static String getColorByCode(int colorCode) {
    if(reverseLookUp.get(colorCode) == null)
      return null;
    else 
      return reverseLookUp.get(colorCode).color;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will throw a `NullPointerException` if the color code is not found in the map. You should do `Map<Integer, String>` or check if the return value of `get` is `null` before accessing a field on it.

Comment: You don't need to call `get` twice. Do something like `err = reverseLookUp.get(colorCode); return err == null ? null : err.color;` You can replace the ternary op with `if(err != null) return err.color; return null;` if you have a preference that way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of straightforward options available to you. One is to use a `Map<Integer, String>` and another is to to a linear search.

Using a map is probably much more efficient, but will take up more space. This is probably not an issue for a small number of enums.

```
public enum KDErrors {

  KDR_280(280, "Blue"),
  KDR_281(281, "Red"),
  KDR_282(282, "Green"),
  KDR_284(284, "Yellow"),

  private static Map<Integer, String> codeMap = new HashMap<>();

  private final int code;
  private final String color;

  private KDErrors(int code, String color) {
    this.code = code;
    this.color = color;
    codeMap.put(code, color);
  }

  public static String getColorByCode(int colorCode) {
   return codeMap(colorCode);
  }
}
```

Doing a linear search prevents you from having to allocate additional structures, but it will be a little slower for the average case than a lookup in a `HashMap`:

```
public enum KDErrors {

  KDR_280(280, "Blue"),
  KDR_281(281, "Red"),
  KDR_282(282, "Green"),
  KDR_284(284, "Yellow"),

  private final int code;
  private final String color;

  private KDErrors(int code, String color) {
    this.code = code;
    this.color = color;
  }

  public static String getColorByCode(int colorCode) {
   for(KDErrors err : KDErrors.values()) {
       if(err.getCode() == colorCode)
           return error.getColor();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jens. Because it is generally a better approach than doing a linear search over a whole rack of items. It won't matter much if there are only a couple of items in the enum, but as the number grows, the map approach will start to shine.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the catch. It was just a stupid copy-n-paste error. Fixed now.